# Sending a link towards Intent with SmsManager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, smsmanager

I'm trying to send an Sms thanks to the SmsManager of Android. I'd like this sms to contain a link towards my application, and to open a specific activity.
Do you have any idea how to achieve this? Or if it is even possible?

**EDIT:** I've seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477762/how-to-start-activity-over-incoming-sms-in-android) but it was asked 3 years ago and I'm guessing the method has changed...?

I was hoping to achieve something like this:
"Hello, Jonathan would like to be added inside your group 'The Happy People'. **Follow this link to answer him**!"

That way the user could click on the link and be redirected to my app...

Or maybe I could use [notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)? But the good thing about sms is that I have the phone number of the person I'd like to contact so it's easier... whereas for notifications, I can't use the phone number...

I can't find anyone trying to achieve this result... ):

**EDIT:** I finally used notifications with GCM... Never found a real convenient solution to my problem

Comment: Seems you can :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477762/how-to-start-activity-over-incoming-sms-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send Email Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)